# How to remove focus from textfield and set it on button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtextfield

It is the simple counter gui program in these program by pressing right arrow counter is incremented by 1 but the problem is whenever i run the program then pressing the right arrow the counter is not increment by 1 but by pressing the right arrow the cursor in textfield shifts from left to right why this happens ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class CounterDemo implements KeyListener
{
    JTextField jtf;
    JButton jb,jb1;
    int i=0;
    public CounterDemo ()
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setBounds(100,100,400,400);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(null);


        jtf = new JTextField("0");
        jtf.setBounds(60,10,50,20);
        jf.add(jtf);

        JButton jb = new JButton("next");
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("prev");
        jb.setBounds(10,35,75,20);
        jb1.setBounds(90,35,75,20);

        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jb1);

        jb.addKeyListener(this);
        jb1.addKeyListener(this);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CounterDemo();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            i++;
            jtf.setText(" "+i);
        }
        else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            i--;
            jtf.setText(" "+i);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Is your code simply an exercise in learning _Swing_? Your `KeyListener` will run when the `JButton` has focus. To understand how focus works, see [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). For a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) you should add an `ActionListener` and not a `KeyListener`. In any case [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) are usually better than `KeyListener`.

Comment: Maybe [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) is more appropriate?

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I agree with @Abra re the `JSpinner`. It is perfectly designed for this. OTOH if sticking with the text field / button combo, add an `ActionListener` rather than a `KeyListener`. And fix that layout!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `jtf.setFocusable(false)` so that the text field is not in focus initially.

Edit: As [Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164365/abra) said, this would make the text field never be in focus. An alternative solution is to do something like `jb.grabFocus()`, for the button to get focus instead of the text field.

Comment: _so that the text field is not in focus initially_ The text field will **never** be in focus. There are other ways to set the initially focused component.

Comment: True, I have edited my answer based on your comment. Thanks!